# Is there any trade-off between using parameter in the flask factory method vs using an env variable?

Tags: python, flask

In flask (example - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/#basic-factories), following is the code provided:

```
def create_app(config_filename):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)

    from yourapplication.model import db
    db.init_app(app)

    from yourapplication.views.admin import admin
    from yourapplication.views.frontend import frontend
    app.register_blueprint(admin)
    app.register_blueprint(frontend)

    return app
```

Is there any advantage of using the parameter for the factory method over for example we could even - not use the parameter and replace `app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)` with `app.config.from_pyfile(os.getenv('env_var', 'dev'))`? Is there any limitation to using the env var approach?